# Geo Location marker using Ionic Framework and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am trying to show the current location of a user using Ionic Framework, AngularJS and Google Maps. The marker of the current location is not showing. If an other solution exist to show a blue point of the current location (like un gmaps) let me know.

If anyone can see where i am wrong please let me know. Thank you.

The controller :

```
.controller('GeomapCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, GeomapService) {

  $scope.$on('mapInitialized', function(event, map) {

    $scope.positions = [];

    $scope.map = map;

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      $scope.positions.push({lat: pos.k,lng: pos.B});
      console.log(pos);
      $scope.map.setCenter(pos);
    });

  });

})
```

The view :

```
<map data-tap-disabled="true" zoom="15" disable-default-u-i="true" default-style="false" style="display:block;height:100%;">
           <marker ng-repeat=" pos in positions" position="{{pos.lat}},{{pos.lng}}"></marker>
    </map>
```

Comment: try using `$apply` inside `geolocation` callback since it is updating scope outside of angular

Comment: This is exactly that. thank you so much !